# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated from another view controller class

Tags: iphone

I do have two ViewController class,  one firstviewController other secondViewController in first viewcontroller i call this `[self dimissModalViewControllerAnimation:NO];`
to dimiss the view!  now i need to dimiss the same view from another secondViewController class.

So do i need to call super in that!

```
[super dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Or Do i need to create any protocol for dismissing the view! from another secondViewController class.

Can any guide me with this issue.

Comment: does your second view controller class inherit from the first one?  or are they both separate UIViewController subclasses?

Comment: I think protocol would suffice your requirement..

Comment: @Nate Both are separate UIViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can register a notification in firstViewController's viewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"MyNotification" object:nil];
```

Add the event handler in firstViewController

```
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification*)note {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Then you can trigger the event in secondViewController

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyNotification" object:nil ];
```

Comment: !  its the perfect to use notification

Answer (score 1):

You should only be using `super` when you're overloading a method definition, e.g.:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Login / Signup";
}
```

Typically, if you're trying to tell one view to do something from another view, delegates are your friend. You could create a weak `delegate` variable to hold a reference to the view controller to be dismissed, and call `[delegate dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Comment: I assume you meant to say that you would hold a reference to the  **view controller** that will do the dismissing, since `UIViewController` has `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`